# How to make a python object json-serialized?

Tags: python, mysql, json, django, orm

I want to `serialize a python object`, after saved it into `mysql`(based on Django ORM) I want to get it and pass this object to a function which need this kind of object as a param.

Following two parts are my main logic code:

> 1 save param part :

```py
class Param(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, targeting=None, start_time=None, end_time=None):
        self.name = name
        self.targeting = targeting
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.end_time = end_time
    #...

param = Param()
param.name = "name1"
param.targeting= "targeting1"


task_param = {
            "task_id":task_id,              # string
            "user_name":user_name,          # string
            "param":param,                  # Param object
            "save_param":save_param_dict,   # dictionary
            "access_token":access_token,    # string
            "account_id": account_id,       # string
            "page_id": page_id,             # string
            "task_name":"sync_create_ad"    # string
        }


class SyncTaskList(models.Model):
    task_id = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    ad_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    task_status = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    task_fail_reason = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    task_param = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'sync_task_list'



SyncTaskList(
                task_id=task_id,
                ad_name=param.name,
                user_name=user_name,
                task_status=0,
                task_param = task_param,
            ).save()
```

> 2 use param part

```py
def add_param(param, access_token):
    pass

task_list = SyncTaskList.objects.filter(task_status=0)
for task in task_list:
    task_param = json.loads(task.task_param)
    add_param(task_param["param"], task_param["access_token"]) # pass param object to function add_param
```

If I directly use `Django ORM` to save task_param into mysql, I get error,

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

for after ORM operation, I get string who's property name enclosed in single quotes like :

```
# in mysql it saved as 

 task_param: " task_param: {'task_id': 'e4b8b240cefaf58fa9fa5a591221c90a',
              'user_name': 'jimmy',
              'param': Param(name='name1',
                                    targeting='geo_locations',
                                   ),
              'save_param': {}}"
```

I am now confused with serializing an python object, then how to load this original object and pass it to a function?

Any commentary is very welcome. great thanks.

> update my solution so far

```py
task_param = {
            # ...
            "param":vars(param),            # turn Param object to dictionary 
            # ...
            }

SyncTaskList(
                #...
                task_param = json.dumps(task_param),
                #...
            ).save()

#task_list = SyncTaskList.objects.filter(task_status=0)
#for task in task_list:
    task_param = json.loads(task.task_param)
    add_param(Param(**task_param["param"]), task_param["access_token"])
```

> update based on @AJS's answer

directly `pickle dumps` and saved it as an `binary field`, then `pickle loads`it also works

Any better solution for this?

Comment: If i understand it correctly in MySql you are saving task_param as string,under column task_param, and you are saving it with single quotes. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Use `json.dumps(obj)` to convert `obj` to JSON.

Comment: @KlausD. It will raise error `TypeError: Object of type 'Param' is not JSON serializable
`

Comment: @AJS yeah,  that's true if i directly save it as my above codes showed , it automaticly turn to single quotes style

Comment: The `obj` has to be a simple Python structure, made out of builtin types like dictionaries, list, strings, numbers... Your `param` key is not.

Comment: @thasks for your reply,Do  you mean I should convert an `obj` to a key-value dictionary according to `obj's properties`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) basically you are serializing your python object and save it as bytes in your MySQL db using `BinaryField` as your model field type in Django, as i don't think JSON serialization would work in your case as you have a python object as a value as well in your dict, when you fetch your data from db simpily unpickle it syntax is similar to json library see below.

```
import pickle
#to pickle
data = pickle.dumps({'name':'testname'})
# to unpickle just do
pickle.loads(data)
```

so in your case when you unpickle your object you should get your data in same form as it was before you did pickle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply,  after `pickle.dump` I can get a bytes data, but when saved it into mysql by `Django ORM` it turn to be a string, and I cannot loads it back anymore

Comment: use `pickle.dumps` it should be string, you missed `s`

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into msgpack
https://msgpack.org/index.html

unlike pickle, which is python-specific, msgpack is supported by many languages (so the language you use to write to mysql *can* be different than the language used to read).

There are also some projects out there that integrate these serializer-libraries into Django model fields:

- Pickle: https://pypi.org/project/django-picklefield/
- MsgPack: https://github.com/vakorol/django-msgpackfield/blob/master/msgpackfield/msgpackfield.py